# has_one and migration issue in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I have following models

- Address
- Car
- User

And I have following relationship among the model.

- Every Car has one address (one - one relationship)
- Every User has one address (one - one relationship)

Address model

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Car Model

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

Database Table

- Car has a column address_id as foreign key
- User has a column address_id as foreign key

Migrations
User

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      ...

      t.references :Address, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

Car Migration

```
class CreateCars < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :cars do |t|
      t.string :chasis
      ...

      t.references :Address, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

Now when I try to create a nested form from User/new.html.erb I get following error.

***user_id is unknown attribute in Address.***

User_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_address
  end

  ...
end
```

My nested form is not getting rendered.

Nested form

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f|%>
  <%= f.fields_for :address do |fact| %>
    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= f.label :add1, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <%= f.text_field :add1, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= f.label :add2, class: 'col-sm-2 control-label' %>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <%= f.text_field :add2, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2">
      <%= f.submit class: 'form-control btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
  </div>      
<% end %>
```

I suspect that there is some issue in my migration files. but the database tables are created in the manner I want.

Comment: Please post `CreateAddresses` migration.

Comment: I think u don't have user_id in address migration.

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure but:

```
 t.references :Address, foreign_key: true
```

shouldn't be

```
 t.references :address, foreign_key: true
```

notice the small (a) in `:address`

Answer (score 0):

User id is not there.

first You have to save the user. Can you try fact.addr instead of f.addr

Can you post full code of User Controller file.

```
<%= form_for @person, url: {action: "create"} do |person_form| %>
  <%= person_form.text_field :name %>
  <%= fields_for @person.contact_detail do |contact_detail_form| %>
    <%= contact_detail_form.text_field :phone_number %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>


<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/people" class="new_person" id="new_person" method="post">
  <input id="person_name" name="person[name]" type="text" />
  <input id="contact_detail_phone_number" name="contact_detail[phone_number]" type="text" />
</form>
```

if save @person it will automatically save data for contact also.

Please refer this link for more info

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html